# pl/sql join two files and read them

Tags: oracle, bash, file, unix, utl-file

I need to join multiple files into a single one to read it from my external table
Since these files are named 'randomly' (anyway I can find a pattern) for example:

```
ADG_LOZX723536.txt
ADG_LOZX142596.txt
```

I have a pkg that executes operations reading the external table and this would be a scheduled job.

How can I join it via PL/SQL having these files named differently so that I can execute my PKG and other things?

I thought to create a single job which calls a bash script
This script just joins the files, (grep them by regex) into a single one which would be read by the external table. Then run the pkg via sqlplus

Anyway there is another way to just use PL/SQL?

Thank you

Comment: What are the contents of the files?

Comment: Check out UTL_FILE.

Comment: Can you something like `echo exit | sqlplus user/password@connect @<(cat filenames)` ?

Comment: @Miguel, hi, UTL_FILE doesn't let me to join multiple file, I'm already using it on other packages

Comment: @WalterA I'll try it and let you know, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 11g they added preprocessing support for external tables. This allows us to associate an OS (shell) script with the table; this script is run whenever we execute a query on the table. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN12898).

In your situation you could write a shell script to identify and munge the various files into a single source file for the table. This would be neater than having a job to call the shell script.

The PL/SQL purist in me would like to recommend a wholly in-database approach but let's be honest, shell scripts are way better suited to OS file manipulation than stored procedures.

Comment: gonna try it and let you know, ty

Comment: KUP-04095: preprocessor command encountered error "error during exec: errno is 2", my script is 755 (oracle:oinstall), it just execute echo "test" > test.txt
but I'm getting this, any idea?

Comment: Could be anything. Does the shell script run when you execute it in the  OS as the `oracle` user? What is the `$PATH` setting?